# Seleccionar nulo y todo el contenido de una tabla

Tags: mysql, select

Necesito hacer una query la cual el primer campo a mostrar sea nulo y los demas resultados sean la seleccion de todos los campos de una tabla.

Trate con `SELECT NULL, * FROM tabla`, pero da error de sintaxis en mysql.
Se que en SQL Server se puede hacer, pero no tengo idea como en mysql.
La idea es mas o menos asi:

```
|      | Campo1 | Campo2 | Campo3 | Campo4 |
|------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| NULL |        |        |        |        |
```

Esto lo necesito para una bitacora , el cual el primer campo debe ser el Id de la bitacora con autoincremental y lo demas todos los campos de la tabla.

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas un resultado así?

Comment: No creo que necesites un `select null`, mas bien necesitas hacer un join de la bitácora con la tabla.

Comment: Es una bitacora que ya estaba hecha, pero antes no tenia un id propio, sino que copiaba todo el contenido de la tabla a la bitacora si existia un cambio, con una clausula `where Id=NEW.Id` y me pidieron ahora agregar un capo Id propio para la bitacora, el cual sea autincremental y que copie la demas informacion de la tabla origen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el resultado deseado, lo que no puedes utilizar es el `*` para indicar todos los campos, sino que debes enumerarlos:

```
select null, campo1, campo2 from tabla;
```

Comment: A las finales tuveque utiliza este metodo. El unico inconveniente es que son bastante los campos y tendre que inventar otro metodo mas adelante para crear la bitacora. Igual agradecido estimado.